# Working with an extremely unbalanced and poorly correlated dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am working with a difficult dataset, in that the classes are both highly unbalanced and extremely uncorrelated. The set has 96,000 values, of which less than 200 are 1s.

I have tried a few methods, and with each the precision and accuracy were always high, however only a few (less than 5) values are being classified as 1. I wonder if there is a way to force the machine to classify more 1s. If I could classify correctly just 25% of the time, this would be a great result.

I have tried using random forest's 'class weight' parameter, but this doesn't seem to have any effect on the result.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sklearn
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_pickle('/Users/shellyganga/Downloads/ola.pickle')

print(df.describe())

#filtering the df to improve results
df = df[(df['trip_duration'] > 5) & (df['Smooth_Driving_Score'] < 99)]

print(df.describe())


maxVal = 1
df.unsafe = df['unsafe'].where(df['unsafe'] <= maxVal, maxVal)

df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.columns[-2], axis=1, inplace=True)

#setting features and labels
labels = np.array(df['unsafe'])
features= df.drop('unsafe', axis = 1)

# Saving feature names for later use
feature_list = list(features.columns)

# Convert to numpy array
features = np.array(features)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# 30% examples in test data
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels,
                                                          stratify = labels,
                                                          test_size = 0.4,
                                                          random_state = 12)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# Create the model with 100 trees
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,
                               random_state=12,
                               max_features = 'sqrt',
                               n_jobs=-1, verbose = 1, class_weight={0:1, 1:1})

# Fit on training data
model.fit(train, train_labels)
predictions = model.predict(test)


print(np.mean(predictions))
print(predictions.shape)


from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(test_labels, predictions)
```

Output:

```
     precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       1.00      1.00      1.00     38300
          1       1.00      0.01      0.02        90

avg / total       1.00      1.00      1.00     38390
```

I tried using `{class_weight = 'balanced'}` and provided a different result, but I am having trouble understanding it.

```
   micro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     38390
   macro avg       1.00      0.51      0.51     38390
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     38390
```

How do I know how many positives it has predicted?

Comment: class_weight is the way to do it. What values did you try? From the docs, it looks like you should try class_weight='balanced' which will automatically create something roughly like `{0:(200.0/96000), 1:1}`

Comment: thanks, I added an edit with the output I got but I still don't understand it

Comment: A couple of solutions that I read about (but haven't tried) to work with unbalanced sets are: (i) duplicate the minority flag until the set is more or less balanced and (ii) randomly choose, in your case 200, from the majority flag, so that the data is balanced. Method i is supposed to be better.

Answer (score 0):

This extent of imbalance is generally pretty difficult to get around especially if you have a lot of features (due to curse of dimensionality). Unless there is a very distinct boundary between the two classes, it will be difficult to identify the minority class from the overwhelming majority class. As suggested by Luke and Tacratis, both class weight and oversampling/undersampling are good approaches that you should try. In addition, I would also suggest using an appropriate cost metric. For example, if false positives are more desirable than false negatives, try to maximize Recall, instead of precision or accuracy. I would also recommend a combination of these approaches. So, let's say

1. Oversample minority class to 1000 rows. Try SMOTE while oversampling.
2. Undersample minority class to 5000-10000 rows.
3. Apply class weights to create balanced sets.
4. Evaluate your cost metric on the test set and change the above numbers until metric is maximized.

All this said, it is entirely possible that you may not have enough samples of the minority class for a well trained model. This will be the case if you are able to achieve a high value of the cost metric on the training set, but are unable to generalize the metric on the test set.